# Print PDF to default printer after setting default printer in Python

Tags: python, file, printing, default

When I change default printer and then use;
 `win32api.shellexecute(0,'print',filename,None,'.',0)` 
all print jobs are still being sent to the first default printer set first in python

```
def printfile(filename):
    while True:
        printername=input("printername:")
        import win32print,time,win32api
        try:

            global defaultPrinter
            defaultPrinter=None
            defaultPrinter = win32print.GetDefaultPrinter()
            if defaultPrinter != printername:
                time.sleep(0.5)
                win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(printername)
            time.sleep(0.5)
                
            win32api.ShellExecute (
            0,
            "print",
            filename,
            None, ".", 0)       
            
            time.sleep(3)
            
            win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(defaultPrinter)
        except Exception as err:
            print(err)
        
printfile('Black.pdf')
```

I tried to change the default printer through my program but all print jobs will send to the first default printer set at the beginning of my program running.

Comment: change the time delay `time.sleep(0.5)`  after `win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(printername)` to two seconds

Comment: change the time delay time.sleep(4) did not help me.

Comment: "black.pdf" is my file name not a virus. I checked after changing printer default that other programs like msword-office  acts correct by the new default printer also in device and printer my default printer has chhanged also i n registry but in my program it does not act correctly.print